# are 2D arrays linear data structure

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

If linear/non-linear data structures are distinguished by how these data structures allocate the memory for the data entries, does that mean that a multi-dimensional array is still considered a linear data structure?

Comment: The way a program allocate memory for a data structure does not depend on the data structure itself, but also on the actual implementation of this data structure (and to a lesser extent, on the architecture you run it on). So I'm not sure there is a simple yes/no answer to your question.

Comment: I want to learn about the complexity of this question. That’s why I asked. Please answer with details. Thanks!